# 4D Write Error 1022

Tags: mysql, document, 4d-database

I am preparing to export the data of a 4D Database (version 11) to a MySQL database.

The 4D field is a picture field with a 4D Write document saved in it. I can see that a document is stored in the picture field (when exported to MySQL blob), but most of the documents are so old that 4D generates an error "Unknown document type" when the document is trying to be loaded in 4D.

I am guessing that the original 4D Write document was created in a much older version of 4D Write which the newer version of 4D Write can't read.

It's sad, because I can read the document when I export the picture to a blob in MySQL.

Newer documents can be migrated using the following:

```
$Area:=WR New offscreen area 
WR PICTURE TO AREA ($Area;[Notes]Note_)
```

However, the older "unreadable" documents generate a 4D Write error 1022.

Data in MySQL when viewed as text looks like this: [image: screenshot]

And when viewed as a picture (using Sequel Pro), the document is formatted and perfectly readable.

Not looking for a formatted document, just text with paragraphs (carriage returns).

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the version of 4D that created the data.

Comment: I believe the data was created using "4D version 3" and "4D Write version 3".

Answer (score 0):

There was a **bug** in *v11* (ACI0073747) regarding opening older 4D Write documents on Mac OS. The same issue also existed in early version of *v12* (ACI0077678).

*The issue was **Mac only***, so the *workaround* was to use Windows to open the 4D Write document. Opening the document would cause a sort of update or conversion of the document to occur, once the document/record was then re-saved it could then be opened on Mac again.

The bug was **fixed in v12.5** and should be working in the final release of v12 which is 12.6 as well as the current versions of 4D including v14.4 and v15.1

The bug fix list including the actual fix is here:
http://download.4d.com/Documents/Products_Documentation/LastVersions/Line_12/US/BugsFixedLists/12_5/Fixed_Bugs_4D_Write_12.5.pdf